# Disable read/write workqueue for Ubuntu Full-Disk-Encryption

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, luks, cryptsetup, dm-crypt

I am currently trying to set up multiple devices with Ubuntu (20.04.5 LTS) and the drive must be encrypted, so I used LUKS during the installation. (I checked "Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation" + "Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for Security" in the process)

However, the encrypted drive is much slower (as expected), but I read [this article](https://blog.cloudflare.com/speeding-up-linux-disk-encryption/) about the possibility to speed up dm-crypt I/O operations, using two flags `no_read_workqueue`
and `no_write_workqueue` (last paragraph). FYI: I am using a NVMe SSD. The patch has been merged into the Linux Kernel 5.9 and onwards, I have 5.14, so it should be available for me. How can I enable this by default?

I have already changed the `/etc/crypttab` file by adding the flags:

`nvme0123abcdef-etc UUID=123abcdef-etc none luks,discard,no-write-workqueue,no-read-workqueue`

That hasn't changed the speed at all.

I tried to set the default flags:

`cryptsetup --perf-no_read_workqueue --perf-no_write_workqueue --persistent refresh root`

then I will get an error: `--perf-no_read_workqueue: unknown option`

Furthermore the flags are not shown when I use `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdaX | grep Flags` -> (This shows "none") or `dmsetup table` -> (This shows `allow_discards`)

FYI: I used this Wikipage for infos: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Specialties

Comment: Duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/1116583/disable-read-write-workqueue-for-ubuntu-full-disk-encryption#new-answer

Answer (score 2):

I had the same idea with Debian 11.

After modifying /etc/crypttab you need to run

```
sudo update-initramfs -k all -u
```

to update the boot config.
If this command shows a warning, these options are not supported on your system. This is the case with Debian 11 (but runtime changes are supported).

You can check the current flags using this command:

```
sudo dmsetup table nvme0n1p3_crypt --showkeys
0 3515592704 crypt aes-xts-plain64 :64:logon:cryptsetup:asdf-asdf-asdf-asdf 0 259:3 32768 1 allow_discards
```

You can change the options during runtime using:

```
sudo cryptsetup refresh  nvme0n1p3_crypt --perf-no_read_workqueue  --perf-no_write_workqueue --allow-discards
```

Unfortunately, it forces you the enter the disk encryption key again which makes automation hard.

However, the options do not seem to be without drawbacks.
On my system (Ryzen 2700 + WD SN570 2TB) the sequential write performance drops by 25% while the random I/O performance increases by 30%.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that your `cryptsetup` package is too old. Support for these performance flags were added in version 2.3.4 (see [release notes](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/cryptsetup/v2.3/v2.3.4-ReleaseNotes)), but Ubuntu 20.04 only provides version 2.2.2 (see [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/cryptsetup)).

So your best bet is probably to upgrade to a newer distro.